# Storing oil coated and unrefrigerated egg

Tags: storage-method, eggs

Is there any truth to coating eggs with oil, placing them in the cartons upside down and then not storing them in the refrigerator - will make them last a few months???

Answer (score 2):

Conceivably, as the oil would block the pores in the egg shell and prevent evaporation/contamination. However, the oil would also eventually absorb in through the shell, so I would certainly avoid using mineral oil as some sites suggest, as it's toxic.

Having said that, I'm not sure of the logic behind storing them upside down.

Comment: If you were to use food-grade mineral oil, you'd probably be okay, since it's specifically treated to be non-toxic.

Comment: If you dip the bottom half then flip, it'll trickle down over the top half? That's the only reasoning I can think of for storing them upsidown.